# Create percentage bar in label like kcachegrind using graphviz

Tags: graphviz, dot

I'm trying to create a callgraph similar to kcachegrind using graphviz.  See e.g.,

[image: callgraph]

I thought I could create the percentage bar using a table with a row using two cells, setting their size and background color.  This sort of works, except that by default it will make the bar as wide as the widest column (the function label).  If I add `fixedsize="TRUE"`  the cells get the expected width, but now space is inserted between the cells to make the total width still equal to the total table width.  I also tried nested tables, but that seems to give the same result.  `cellspacing(0)` only seems to affect vertical spacing.

I had a look at the kcachegrind source.  They seem to just reserve a line and do the percentage bar themselves (parse the dot layout info and draw the nodes directly on the canvas).  This suggests it it may not be possible to do this in graphviz.  The related solution I can opt for is to post-process
the SVG, but that seems pretty ugly ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [colorList](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#k:colorList) in the `bgcolor` attribute of the cell to imitate a progressbar.

Example:

```
digraph {
    example1 [
        shape=plain
        label=<
            <table cellborder="0" cellspacing="5">
                <tr><td colspan="2">Title</td></tr>
                <tr><td border="1" width="50" bgcolor="#6da8ce;0.25:white"></td><td color="white">25%</td></tr>
            </table>
        >
    ]

    example2 [
        shape=plain
        label=<
            <table cellborder="0" cellspacing="5">
                <tr><td colspan="2">Title</td></tr>
                <tr><td border="1" width="50" bgcolor="#6da8ce;0.71:white"></td><td color="white">71%</td></tr>
            </table>
        >
    ]
}
```

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: Works perfect!  Had to add `fixedsize="TRUE"` to avoid the bar being the same size as the label, but that is detail.   Also note that if the bar value is exactly 0 you get a gradient, so you should just specify `white`

Comment: This seems to be **very** labor intensive... did you do this one-by-one?

Comment: @Trailer you just have to put some effort into the first one and then copy it around with small adjustments. If the task is too common you can create a template in your editor (Sublime and VScode allow doing that for example). But you are right, many things that seem trivial require a lot of work in Graphviz. That is a price for flexibility of low-level tools.